# only top-border is showing not complete border around container

Tags: html, css, layout, border

1. Border is **not displayed properly**.**Side** and **bottom** ones
   are **missing**.
2. here shorthand property is acting like top-border
   property.
3. If we apply height tag to container than container than
   borders are displayed correctly but it should work on its own.

CSS

```
.container
{
  border:1px solid black;
}
.container DIV
{
 width: 15px;
 border: 1px solid Blue;
 margin: 1px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div style="width: 200px; " class="container">
   <div style="float: left;">1</div>
   <div style="float: left;">2</div>
   <div style="float: left;">3</div>
   <div style="float: left;">4</div>
   <div style="float: right;">5</div>
   <div style="float: right;">6</div>
   <div style="float: right;">7</div>
   <div style="float: right;">8</div>
</div>
```

Comment: the jsfiddle does not have any css

Comment: the fiddle is not really complete..

Comment: modify your fiddle, have a look. http://jsfiddle.net/kheema/CqNMG/19/

Comment: i have created fiddle using your code. working fine. http://jsfiddle.net/sureshponnukalai/4rkLJ/. which browser this issue is coming?

Comment: sorry to all i m new user @SamDenton  i have edited it

Comment: @suresh  remove height:100 px in div style part     and i have edited my code too. sorry for that. now no mistakes

Comment: given answer. Check it out.

Comment: @suresh yup its working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your container class like below.

```
.container
{
border:1px solid black; 
display:table;
}
```

[**Fiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/sureshponnukalai/4rkLJ/3/)

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide more code (including the html that shows the actual container element).  However, my guess from what you have said is that adding overflow:hidden to your style should fix it.

```
 .container
            {border:1px solid black;
            margin:auto;
            margin-top:33px;
            overflow:hidden;
            }
```

If elements within your container are floating, then the container acts like it has a height of 0.  This would cause a border to be a single line at the top.  Overflow:hidden  gives it the height including any floating elements (see http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#root-height )

As I say, more code would be required to say if that is what the issue is in your case but it is a common cause of that style problem.

Comment: @ Richard but u have highlighted the  cause of the problem thank you!!!. ur contribution to flowing stream was necessary.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using `float` property on child elements. to fix it just use `overflow:hidden` on parent element i.e. in your case use add `overflow` on class `.container`.

Here is a **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/qiborexi/1/edit)**.

```
.container
{
  border:1px solid black;
  overflow:hidden;/* Added Line*/
}
```